# IDEA - unmute one breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, breakpoints

I have many breakpoints in methods which some times from any places in my code. And at time when I want to catch only one method calling and I don't know any conditions, I necessary to mute some breakpoints.
How can I mute all my breakpoints and unmute only one of it? 
Or it is impossible?

Comment: You could  enable/disable breakpoints in "Breakpoints Window": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/breakpoints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window "Breakpoints" (Run -> View Breakpoints) allows enable/disable all breakpoints and enable/disable only one.